# Tf changeset latest with a different login

Tags: powershell, tfs, psexec, changeset

I want to get the latest changeset from powershell. I can do this with

```
$changesetText= tf changeset /latest /server:${TFSServer} |out-string
```

But this requires access to whole Team Project Collection, as the changeset number is used across all branches.  Is there any way I can get it with /login?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about the problem you're trying to solve?  Do you really need the latest changeset for the entire project collection?  Let's say you have access to `$/A` but not `$/B`, and the latest changeset beneath `$/A` is 4 and the latest beneath `$/B` is 5.  If you don't have access to `$/B`, how does any knowledge about `$/B`'s changesets help you?

Comment: Then I can get a difference 1 and 4, i.e. if difference=1~4                                           
$ChangeHistoryDiff= tf history /format:detailed /r "/server:${TFSServer}" /version:${difference} ${LocalSourceRoot}| out-string

Comment: Can you just use `T` as a versionspec in order to mean latest - that is `/version:1~T` instead of querying for the latest changeset number?

Comment: I need to get "incremental" latest, i.e. if yesterday I got version 4, today I want to get changed files only to my local folder

Comment: Hmm.  I'm still a little fuzzy.  For example, can you just use a `Workspace` to do incremental gets and let the server handle all this for you?  Can you post your code and/or give a holistic explanation of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I am using TFS to track changes of a tool that does not have a text based files, but only GUI. For each incremental change we import the changes to the other tool, and integrate there.

Answer (score 2):

psexec did work:

```
$changesetText= psexec -u ${username} -p ${password} tf changeset /latest /server:${TFSServer} |out-string

$changeset= "Changeset:"
$user= "User: "
$changeset_len=$changeset.length 

$newChangeset= $changesetText.Substring($changesetText.IndexOf($changeset) + $changeset_len, $changesetText.IndexOf($user) - $changesetText.IndexOf($changeset)- $changeset_len-1)
write-host "Last changeset number is : " $newChangeset
```